# Python scope of variables in and out of a function

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2.

def cube(x):
    return x**3.

def some_func():
    foo['a'] = 1.
    foo['b'] = 3.

    if foo['b'] > foo['a']:
        bar = square
    else:
        bar = cube

foo = dict()

bar = None

some_func()

print(foo['a'])

print(bar(2))
```

Two different variables are initialised in the beginning, `foo`, and `bar`. Then I run a function which doesn't take arguments or return anything, but amends these two variables.

The result of these two is the following:

```
1.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7e5e5ac79215> in <module>
     22 print(foo['a'])
     23 
---> 24 print(bar(2))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So, the dict is happily amended by `some_func()`, but I cannot assign a function name. Why? How can I go around this?

Edit: I have tried giving `bar` other values than `None`, similar behaviour occurs.

Comment: Putting things in the dictionary that `foo` refers to is very different to reassigning the value of the variable `foo`. Your code only reads `foo` (and mutates the dictionary it refers to), but tries to assign to `bar`, so that is the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of some_func() you are adding key-value pairs to the dictionary object referenced by `foo`. You are editing the object directly. `bar` is referencing a `None` object. When you attempt to re-assign the value of the label `bar` inside of `some_func()` it does so, but only for the scope of the function it is in. When it leaves the function whatever the `bar` variable had reference to, `None` in this case, is what it still references.

The difference is that you are manipulating the object `foo` points to, but completely changing which object that `bar` points to. If you could do anything with a `None` object you would be able to manipulate it inside of `some_func()` too.

Some here have offered the `global` option, but unless you are really sure, that is probably not what you want. To truly assign a new value to `bar` you should return it as a result of `some_func()`. Also, you may consider passing in `foo` as a parameter into `some_func()` so that it is clear what variable you are referencing.

```py
def square(x):
    return x**2.

def cube(x):
    return x**3.

def some_func(foo):
    foo['a'] = 1.
    foo['b'] = 3.

    if foo['b'] > foo['a']:
        bar = square
    else:
        bar = cube
    return bar

foo = dict()
bar = some_func(foo)
```

Comment: This is a good answer because it explains the behaviour rather than simply trying to make the error go away with `global`. It may help the OP to consider that variables assigned at a higher level are always accessible to the lower levels (so a variable assigned in the main script is always visible within a function) but the reverse is never true unless you explicitly use the `global` keyword.  The variable `foo` was assigned in the higher level, we are modifying the contents of `foo`, not its assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a global statement for the thing you need to replace (and not just modify):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def square(x):
    return x**2.

def cube(x):
    return x**3.

def some_func():
    global bar

    foo['a'] = 1.
    foo['b'] = 3.

    if foo['b'] > foo['a']:
        bar = square
    else:
        bar = cube

foo = dict()

bar = None

some_func()

print(foo['a'])

print(bar(2))
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the scope in python. You can read more about it in this article: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python.

The given solution for your code would be to add: `global bar` inside the function before the if statements to point it to the global variable that you are trying to set.

Answer (score 1):

In order to assign to the global `bar` from `some_func()`, you need to declare it `global`, like so:

```
def some_func():
    foo['a'] = 1.
    foo['b'] = 3.

    global bar

    if foo['b'] > foo['a']:
        bar = square
    else:
        bar = cube
```

See the [documentation for global](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/global.html), specifically this section:

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire
>   current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be
>   interpreted as globals. While using global names is automatic if they
>   are not defined in the local scope, assigning to global names would be
>   impossible without global.

Your program clearly demonstrates the difference specified here: your access to `foo` is *using* the global name, while your access to `bar` is *assigning* to the global name.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. Is this the "proper" way of doing this stuff? Is there an altogether better way to implement this?

Comment: You almost never want to use globals. While I directly answered your question, @Jon's refactor is better design.